# Display default image when wp_get_attachment_image is empty

Tags: wordpress, image-management

I am using wp_get_attachment_image to bring in a logo for a business in a list of businesses. If there is no logo I want to display a default image.

I know that this doesn't work and have tried a couple of variations:

```
<?php $businessLogo = wp_get_attachment_image($business['logo']);?>
<?php if(empty ($businessLogo)) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/no_image.png" alt="<?php echo $business['name']; ?>" />
<?php } else { echo wp_get_attachment_image($business['logo']) }    ?>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if ( $businessLogo != '' ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($business['logo']);
} else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/no_image.png" alt="<?php echo $business['name']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

That should work since `wp_get_attachment_image` returns an empty string if not set.

Read more about [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) at the WordPress Codex.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_image()` returns an empty string on failure so try this:

```
<?php if ( $businessLogo != '' ) { ?>
    <!-- Display your business logo here -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- Display your default image here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: Didn't let me know you had already posted. Great minds think alike I suppose!

Comment: @michaelrmcneill hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

also try this

i think it's help for you

```
<?php if (isset($businessLogo)) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($business['logo']);
} else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/child-theme/images/no_image.png" alt="<?php echo $business['name']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```